# Lack of taxes in product price and totals

Tags: magento2, configuration, tax

I have products with tax classes - 8-taxable goods and 23-taxable goods. Price of product doesn't include taxes at all. Of course, I was trying to change many of these fields. But if my product has priced $49 it is the same including and excluding tax. In consequence, in checkout, I have no subtotals for taxes.

How it should work? What are the possible steps to add tax to products? Do I need tax rules? Or just adding tax class to product should make its prices different - is it available out of the box, without any deep configuration?

My current configuration of `sales` below:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]